# relative styling won't work with jquery mobile panels

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, position, css-position

I am trying to fill a jquery mobile side panel with a background color with 100% width and 100% height.  I can make it work with absolute positioning, but this gives me some errors in safari and chrome.

Any help would greatly greatly greatly be appreciated.

**CSS**

```
.ContentRightPanel
{
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: pink;
   z-index: 21;
}

#rightpanel
{
  max-width: 13%;
  min-width: 200px; 
  z-index:20;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery mobile side panel**

```
<div data-role="panel" id="rightpanel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay"   data-theme="d" data-swipe-close="false" data-dismissible="false" data-position-fixed="true">

        <div class="ContentRightPanel">

        </div>

</div><!-- /panel -->
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, can you be more specific or rephrase your question?

Comment: I am trying to fill the whole panel with a pink background.  I think I'm running into a compatibility issue with the panels using absolute positioning to do this.  I would prefer to do it with relative positioning.